# Why do numbers alone on lines do not generate errors (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain why these Javascript lines do not generate any errors?
This would generally generate an error in many other languages.
In this case, how are they interpreted by Javascript?

```js
11111111111111111111111;
221.2;
0.11111111111111111111111
4;
5
7,
.22;
.0;
-22;
111111111111111111111/1111111111111111111
+45;
45-12
22+22
```

Comment: At what point/line do you expect error?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar The syntax does not seem valid or complete. Isn't this an error?

Comment: Interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are expressions, and when you enter an expression in the javascript engine, the engine tries to evaluate the expression. but since these expressions are just numbers and operations, the engine has no problem in figuring their values.

however if u tried this x + 3, it will fail, the engine will try to figure its value, and to figure the value of x + 3, it has to evaluate x but x is not defined, so an error will be thrown.

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

**Edit to give a historical view of the reasons behind such a syntax**

---

That is to say, the JS syntax does not force you to have expressions in a statement. And there is a valid reason for that, and that is js is an interpreted language and many interpreted  languages enable expressions to be be alone and not within statements, to make a REPL session more interactive, making these languages easier to interact with - though from a technical point of view, there is no reason that js or any other interpreted language can not enforce such rules, and from a technical point of a view a compiled language statically typed or not can also provide this convenience.

And while js can enforce such rules, interpreted languages often want to be able to execute code as soon as possible, adding such rules will slow this process - so another reason on why to add such a syntax.

Comment: So, what does the number 11111111 evaluate to? Is it simply ignore. Will, in this case, one would use something like 1111111111111111 as a line divider?

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei 11111111 evalutes to 11111111, what do you mean by a line divider? you can have any expression in the console and it will work, unless an error is thrown in evaluating the expression, you could also enter these 
['a','b']
{a:'obj}

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei i have added a historical reason for why often interpreted languages enable such syntax